# Vue: How to trigger transitions for dynamic components instances that use the same template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 with tailwind and I'm having trouble transitioning between dynamic components. As described in the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-enterleave.html#transitioning-between-components), I tried the following:

```
            <transition
              enter-active-class="duration-500 ease-out"
              enter-class="translate-x-full opacity-0"
              enter-to-class="translate-x-0 opacity-100"
              leave-active-class="duration-500 ease-in"
              leave-class="translate-x-0 opacity-100"
              leave-to-class="translate-x-full opacity-0"
              mode="out-in"
            >
              <component :is="elementFormat" :key="elementKey" />
            </transition>
```

Where `elementFormat` obviously refers to the component template that should be rendered. This is a computed property from the vuex store.

Although I can see that `elementFormat` is updated in the console, the transition won't play, unless I wrap a `v-if` or `v-show` around it, and hide it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported the tailwind css correctly because I have recreated your problem and it seems everything works perfectly,

```js
const Demo = {
  data() {
    return {
      view: 'v-a'
    }
  },
  components: {
    'v-a': {
      template: '<div>Component A</div>'
    },
    'v-b': {
      template: '<div>Component B</div>'
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(Demo).mount('#demo')
```

```css
.component-fade-enter-active,
.component-fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.component-fade-enter-from,
.component-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h3>Vue.js Demo</h3>
  <input v-model="view" type="radio" value="v-a" id="a"><label for="a">A</label>
  <input v-model="view" type="radio" value="v-b" id="b"><label for="b">B</label>
  <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
    <component :is="view"></component>
  </transition>
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <h3>Your Code</h3>

  
  <transition enter-active-class="duration-500 ease-out" enter-class="translate-x-full opacity-0" enter-to-class="translate-x-0 opacity-100" leave-active-class="duration-500 ease-in" leave-class="translate-x-0 opacity-100" leave-to-class="translate-x-full opacity-0"
    mode="out-in">
    <component :is="view" />
  </transition>
</div>
```